# JConsole Config

Tags: jconsole

in JBoss' `run.bat`, add:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote - 
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9987 - 
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false - 
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

To start jconsole:

```
JDK/bin>jconsole localhost:9987
```

Comment: Usually with things like this you ask a question and then answer it yourself, I don't think it's meant to be your personal notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should work. If it doesn't, then use 'ps' (or your platform's equivalent) to check whether those arguments are making it on the JVM's command line.

Was that the question?